# Sitecore sub-items sorting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

When there is no sorting of sub-items selected, what is the default sorting method? According to the sitecore documentation:

"If you do not specify a child sorting rule for an item, Sitecore applies the Default child sorting 
rule, and users can sort items manually."

and it defines default as:

"Default: Sort items alphabetically by name, not interpreting leading 
digits as numbers. Leading underscores sort last. This is 
the default child sorting rule."

However, I have a script that enters a bunch of items, and I just want them to show in the order I entered them in (which is essentially the 'created' option) - and then I want the user to have control over how they order it after that. Unfortunately, it doesn't preserve the order I entered them in (and doesn't seem to be the default either).

If I choose any of the sub-items sorting option, then the user can't order it anymore...  how can I do this? Is there someway to set the starting sort-order, and then still have the user order the items?

Comment: "If I choose any of the sub-items sorting option, then the user can't order it anymore... " - don't think that's correct as its just the default sort order I.e. the initial order. Users can still reorder manually with Alt-drag for example. Also I wouldn't be surprised if the ordering process was part of the UI process only, and bypassed by creating items programmatically. You can verify by looking at the sort order field (view std. fields) on the items created - it may be blank. When you reorder via the UI the sort values are often re-shuffled for all siblings also, this may cause problems.

Comment: Hmm - doesn't seem to work - if I choose any of the sorting options, its 'always' set to that option. There is no way for the user to break it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should do is leave the `Subitems Sorting` field empty, then add a sort order value (in the `__Sortorder` field) to each of your items that are being inserted by the script (increase the value by 100 for every item, starting by 100).

That should result in what you want; your items sorted by order of insertion and users can still change their order in the content editor.